# Removing text nodes from element nodes but not from attribute nodes type

Tags: html, dom

How to remove or empty all text nodes from all element nodes but not from attribute nodes in a HTML file with PHP5 DOM? The outputted HTML must contain all the tags and attributes (with the text nodes, that represent the attributes value, untouched) as the original file but with no text, like an empty HTML template.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I'm new to php and don't have much of programming skills either, so I'm not sure what method to use, maybe removeChild, but then, how can I avoid deleting the values from element attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more clear if you show us an example.

Anyway, i think it could be done using regular expressions using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function.

You should first of all define which are the elements you consider as *text nodes* and then use something like this for example:

```
$finalText = preg_replace( "/\<span\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/is", "$1", $originalText);
```

In this case we are deleting the text contained in a *span* node.

And you could keep adding expressions with arrays, like this:

```
    $a = array(
        "/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is",
        "/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/is",
        "/\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/is",
        "/\[t\](.*?)\[\/t\]/is",
        "/\[d\](.*?)\[\/d\]/is",
        "/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/is",
        "/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/is"
    );

    $b = array(
        "$1",
        "$1",
        "$1",
        "$1",       
        "$1",
        "$2",
        ""
    );  

    $finalText = preg_replace($a, $b, $originalText);
```